# FB.ui iFrame/Popups not appearing

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been using the PHP-SDK for wall posts, but I am converting to the Javascript SDK for the familiar popup and callbacks. I've managed to get it working when the app URL points to the Javascript, but I need to be able to call it from an AS3 game.

I'm not sure if it is an authentication issue or an issue calling it. I tried using a console.log and I never saw it in Firebug.

Here is my post code.

```
    <?php
        include 'src/facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '165114483572553',
        'secret' => 'c65114e7dbc8b1eeed9f6535c1aee888', ));

        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $url = $_POST['link'];
        $picture = $_POST['picture'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $userID = $_POST['id'];
    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
      <body>
        <div id='fb-root'></div>
        <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

        <script> 
        console.log("script");
          FB.init({appId: "APP-ID", status: true, cookie: true});
            var caption = "Come Play with Me!";
        var description = 'Sup.';
        var name = 'TaDa';
        var picture = 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg';
        var userID = 'USER-ID';
        var message = 'hello';
        var url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/zombie-kiri';

        postToFeed();
          function postToFeed() {
        console.log("hello post");
            // calling the API ...
            var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              to: userID,
              message: message,
              link: url,
              picture: picture,
              name: name,
              caption: caption,
              description: description,
            };

            function callback(response) {
              document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
          }

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The PHP Authentication at the top was a test as well as the POST variables. With or without the PHP this doesn't run.

Potentially I could use the Graph calls to do this as well, but I want to have access to the Invite Friend menus included in the JS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to invoke [FB.getLoginStatus()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) (and await the callback) before you can start popping Dialogues to the user.

Comment: I tried that previously and it didn't work. I put it back in and looking at the log it is saying the user is not authenticated.

I am also getting this error in the console:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://apps.facebook.com/zombie-kiri/?ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_source=bookmarks_apps&fb_bmpos=1_0 from frame with URL https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#origin=MYHOST&relation=top.frames%5Biframe_canvas%5D&transport=postmessage Domains, protocols and ports must match.`


I omitted some characters due to space.

Answer (score 0):

Had the wrong scope for the function